# How to fetch object with multiple levels of reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-shell

In my project, there are three models:

```
class Level1(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Level2(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        level1 = models.ForeignKey(Level1, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Level3(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        level2 = models.ForeignKey(Level2, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

**Level1** model has 2 objects `WA`, `TX`. **Level2** has 5 objects `AAA`, `BBB` where the foreign key is `WA`; and `AAA`, `CCC`, `DDD` where the foreign key is `TX`.

In **Level3**, I want to add an object `RRRR` where the **Level2** foreign key object is `AAA`.

When I tried to fetch the **Level2** by `Level2.objects.get(name='AAA')`, it shows error `get() returned more than one Level2 -- it returned 2!`

How to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you filter level 2 by name attribute which isn't unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhamdulillah, finally I solve the issue by combining **filter** and **get**.

```
Level2.objects.filter(level1__name='WA').get(name='AAA')
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this is because get method will allow to retrieve only one object you can use

```
Level2.objects.filter(name='AAA')
```

Comment: this will retrieve 2 level2 objects, bother are foreign keyed to different level1 object. I want to add one object in Level3 model.

Answer (score 0):

`get` expects to find only one object and will error otherwise. You can add more lookups

```py
Level2.objects.filter(name='AAA', level1__name='WA') or 
Level2.objects.filter(name='AAA', level1__name='TX')
```

Comment: It shows, "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.".